# Thrift `recv failed` SocketException when using TNonblockingServerSocket

Tags: thrift

I'm trying to use `TNonblockingServerSocket` with `TFramedTransport` on both client and server side but get the following error:
`TTransportException: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed`.

Server code:

```
TServerTransport serverTransport = new TNonblockingServerSocket(9090);
TThreadPoolServer.Args args = new TThreadPoolServer.Args(serverTransport);
args.processor(processor);
args.transportFactory(new TFramedTransport.Factory());
TServer server = new TThreadPoolServer(args);
server.serve();
```

Client code:

```
transport = new TSocket("localhost", 9090);
transport.open();
TProtocol protocol = new  TBinaryProtocol(new TFramedTransport(transport));
Calculator.Client client = new Calculator.Client(protocol);
```

Everything works fine when switching back to `TServerSocket` instead of `TNonblockingServerSocket` - even with the framed transport.

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: Perhaps `TThreadPoolServer` is not meant to handle non-blocking sockets? If so, I can raise a bug so that the `TThreadPoolServer.Args` will explicitly expect only `TServerSocket`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to `THsHaServer` instead of TThreadPoolServer and everything worked fine. Strange.

I Still don't know why it didn't work with `TThreadPoolServer` :(

Comment: I'd guess that the nonblocking socket is to be used by the nonblocking server only.

Comment: So I think that `TThreadPoolServer.Args()` should accept only `TServerSocket` instead of the generic parent `TServerTransport`, because it can't handle `TNonblockingServerSocket`. @JensG, this sounds like a minor bug, agree? If so, I'd like to report it. Starting small on the contribution :)

Comment: Maybe. Discuss it with the C++ people first on the mailing lists and/or freenode, they will be able to give you the 110% answer.

Comment: Yeah, but I said you should disccuss this first.

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned in an earlier comment by JensG, the TNonblockingServerSocket is only intended to be used with TNonblockingServer.

In theory, this information (as well as some other similar information) may be possible to encode in Java's type system.  If you have a specific recommendation, then you can report it here:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT

In practice, some type information can be too difficult or onerous to encode in Java's type system (or C++'s type system, or insert random language here).  In those cases, the problem is often best fixed through documentation, or by failing fast.